# System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I added entity model and context but I get error shown below.

Can you please help me with this?

```
public class SiteDbContext : DbContext
{  private readonly DatabaseSettings _databaseSettings;
public SiteDbContext()
{                 }
public DbSet
<Admission>
Admission { get; set; }          
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);       }    }`
```

Comment: The error message is very self-explanatory.  "No database provider has been configured for this DbContext"  
First question: Did you google the error message?
Second question: If the answer to the first question is "Yes", but you still can't figure it out, then you are going to need to show us your code.

Comment: Yes searched google related that error. below I attached my code please help me on this.
public class SiteDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly DatabaseSettings _databaseSettings;
        public SiteDbContext()
        {
          //  _databaseSettings = databaseSettings;
        }
        public DbSet<Admission> Admission { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }


    }

Comment: Please put the code in your original post so it is properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

> If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

If you have register dbContext like below

```
services.AddDbContext<SiteDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Then you need to modify your DbContext constructor like:

```
public class SiteDbContext: DbContext
{
    public SiteDbContext(DbContextOptions<SiteDbContext> options): base (options)
    {
    }
    //...
}
```